# /bin/sh: aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc-ar: command not found on centos-7

Tags: gcc, centos7, cross-compiling, arm64

I am facing an error of /bin/sh: aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc-ar: command not found

I have already installed the gcc-aarch64-linux-gnu (4.8.5)

Comment: Please do a file search : `yum provides */aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc-ar` : The reply .... *binutils-aarch64-linux-gnu* → `yum install binutils-aarch64-linux-gnu` → provides `/usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc-ar`

Comment: binutils-aarch64-linux-gnu is already present and didn't provide aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc-ar.

Comment: Sorry, the file 'aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc-ar' appeared first time with gcc v5.3.1 : Fedora 22 packages  https://archives.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/updates/22/ ..... + https://archives.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/releases/22/Everything/x86_64/os/Packages/ ......... CentOS 7: I made an OK test install https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1-7_5kB_vUTPIv7ZNvbnAXykPu5UKibqg?usp=sharing